# SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW & TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR no longer working in api level 28?

Tags: android, android-layout, overlay

I have the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission requested in the manifest and the draw overlays permission granted to my application.

However, on API level 26+ my application crashes with permission error 2010 when making adding a view using TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR.

Oddly, when I build for API level 25- it still works for all API levels. Although it behaves like TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY instead of TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR in 26+.

Can someone explain this behavior or how to work around it?

Comment: You should probably read the behavior changes in android O https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#o-apps

Comment: @tyczj That makes sense. What confuses me though is what behaviors this new TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY has. It appears to constrain apps not targeting 28 using TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR to the exact same behavior set.

Is there any documentation on the implied behavior?